# Roboguice Inject into POJO

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

In my application I use RoboGuice for Dependency Injection. In my RoboActivities the injection works fine. If I want to inject something in a POJO like:

```
public class EventController {
    @Inject
    UserController userController;

    @Inject
    public EventController() {}

    public void doSomethingWithUserController {
        //userController is null here
        userController.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Doing it like this my userController is null. What do I have to do to inject the UserController into this POJO?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call this

```
RoboGuice.getInjector(Context).injectMembers(this);
```

in your constructor of EventController. And remove the @Inject Annotation from your constructor.